# Hyphenation of the word "paraboloid"

Tags: tex-core, hyphenation

It seems like my TeX does not hyphenate the word "paraboloid" on its own. After adding `\hyphenation{para-boloid}` (I hope that's the right hyphenation...) to the preamble everything is fine.

My question is: How can I tell whether this (or any other word) is an instance where TeX fails to hyphenate or is it happening because of my setting (e.g. packages in use)? The reason I'm curious here is that I don't consider *paraboloid* an exotic word, and thus I'm surprised it is not hyphenated automatically.

Comment: Barbara Beeton maintains a hyphenation exception log.

Comment: It's an excellent question, though I'm not sure I agree with a hyphen after the letter "a" in "paraboloid".  My dictionary says "pa-rab-o-loid".

Comment: Indeed, in `ushyphex.tex` (available in TeX Live), we find `pa-rab-o-loid` at line 695. For loading this exception list, just do `\input{ushyphex.tex}`.

Comment: you can use `\showhyphens{paraboloid}` to see how tex hyphates this (or any other) word

Comment: @egreg: Why the file `ushyphex.tex` is not loaded automatically? What other exception files can be found?

Comment: @Dror Why should it be loaded automatically? There is no other exception file that I know of. Note that it is only for US English.

Comment: the *u.s.* "exception log" can be viewed as [a pdf file on ctan](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/tb0hyf.pdf).  (i'm working on an updated version; should be available soon.)

Answer (score 8):

whether paraboloid is ‘exotic’ is a matter of personal experience, i think.  i've a mathematics degree and it doesn't surprise me at all, but my wife (with a music degree) may think differently...

in answer to your question, “how do i tell?”, try `\showhyphens` in a plain tex run.  for me, `\showhyphens{paraboloid}` witters about an underfull box, but says

```
    [] \tenrm paraboloid
```

whereas, for a word tex *can* hyphenate, we get

```
    * \showhyphens{peapod}
    Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 0
    [] \tenrm pea-pod
```

fwiw, i have an oxford (pocket-sized) dictionary of "spelling and word divisions".  it gives

```
para|bol|oid
```

but of course, that's the dreaded *british english* hyphenation, and probably doesn't work on the next continent to the left...

Comment: You'd deserve +1 just for the fun! If I activate the British hyphenation patterns, I get `para-bol-oid`. Probably Britons are more into mathematics than their cousins on the other side of the pond.

Comment: @egreg of course the british patterns give the same result: they come from the same database as the book, by kind permission of the oxford university press.  i think i was supposed (as a member of uk tug committee) to sign to say i wouldn't "leak" the content of the database.  i didn't sign, but never actually got anywhere near the raw data.

Comment: I would say that the British are more accurate here. Etymologically "paraboloid" is a compound word, as hyperboloid, with the Greek prefix παρά, and certainly for legibility, the best place for a hyphen in such words is at the end of the prefix. Or someone would accept "param-edic", for instance?